# kube-apiserver docker is restarting continuously

Tags: docker, kubernetes, x509certificate

### Sincere apologies for this lengthy posting.

I have a 4 node Kubernetes cluster with 1 x master and 3 x worker nodes. I connect to the kubernetes cluster using kubeconfig, since yesterday I was not able to connect using kubeconfig.

`kubectl get pods` was giving an error "The connection to the server api.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

In the kubeconfig server name is specified as https://api.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com

### Note:

Please note as there were too many https links, I was not able to post the question. So I have renamed https:// to https:-- to avoid the links in the background analysis section.

I tried to run `kubectl` from the master node and received similar error
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Then checked kube-apiserver docker and it was continuously exiting / Crashloopbackoff.

`docker logs <container-id of kube-apiserver>` shows below errors

> W0914 16:29:25.761524       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc:
> addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:4001 0
> }. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: authentication
> handshake failed: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid".
> Reconnecting... F0914 16:29:29.319785       1 storage_decorator.go:57]
> Unable to create storage backend: config (&{etcd3 /registry
> {[https://127.0.0.1:4001]
> /etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-client.key
> /etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-client.crt
> /etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-ca.crt} false true
> 0xc000266d80 apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1  5m0s 1m0s}), err
> (context deadline exceeded)

`systemctl status kubelet` --> was giving below errors

> Sep 14 16:40:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xx kubelet[2411]: E0914 16:40:49.693576
> 2411 kubelet_node_status.go:385] Error updating node status, will
> retry: error getting node
> "ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xx.xx-xxxxx-1.compute.internal": Get
> https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/nodes/ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xx.xx-xxxxx-1.compute.internal?timeout=10s:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused

Note: ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx --> internal IP address of aws ec2 instance.

### Background Analysis:

Looks there was some issue with the cluster on 7th Sep 2020 and both kube-controller and kube-scheduler dockers exited and restarted. I believe since then kube-apiserver is not running or because of kube-apiserver, those dockers restarted. The kube-apiserver server certificate expired in July 2020 but access via kubectl was working until 7th Sep.

Below are the `docker logs from the exited kube-scheduler` docker container:

> I0907 10:35:08.970384       1 scheduler.go:572] pod
> default/k8version-1599474900-hrjcn is bound successfully on node
> ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.xx-xxxxxx-x.compute.internal, 4 nodes evaluated, 3
> nodes were found feasible I0907 10:40:09.286831       1
> scheduler.go:572] pod default/k8version-1599475200-tshlx is bound
> successfully on node ip-1x-xx-xx-xx.xx-xxxxxx-x.compute.internal, 4
> nodes evaluated, 3 nodes were found feasible I0907 10:44:01.935373
> 1 leaderelection.go:263] failed to renew lease
> kube-system/kube-scheduler: failed to tryAcquireOrRenew context
> deadline exceeded E0907 10:44:01.935420       1 server.go:252] lost
> master lost lease

Below are the docker logs from exited kube-controller docker container:

> I0907 10:40:19.703485       1 garbagecollector.go:518] delete object
> [v1/Pod, namespace: default, name: k8version-1599474300-5r6ph, uid:
> 67437201-f0f4-11ea-b612-0293e1aee720] with propagation policy
> Background I0907 10:44:01.937398       1 leaderelection.go:263] failed
> to renew lease kube-system/kube-controller-manager: failed to
> tryAcquireOrRenew context deadline exceeded E0907 10:44:01.937506
> 1 leaderelection.go:306] error retrieving resource lock
> kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get https:
> --127.0.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager?timeout=10s:
> net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
> headers) I0907 10:44:01.937456       1 event.go:209]
> Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Endpoints", Namespace:"kube-system",
> Name:"kube-controller-manager",
> UID:"ba172d83-a302-11e9-b612-0293e1aee720", APIVersion:"v1",
> ResourceVersion:"85406287", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason:
> 'LeaderElection' ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx_1dd3c03b-bd90-11e9-85c6-0293e1aee720
> stopped leading F0907 10:44:01.937545       1
> controllermanager.go:260] leaderelection lost I0907 10:44:01.949274
> 1 range_allocator.go:169] Shutting down range CIDR allocator I0907
> 10:44:01.949285       1 replica_set.go:194] Shutting down replicaset
> controller I0907 10:44:01.949291       1 gc_controller.go:86] Shutting
> down GC controller I0907 10:44:01.949304       1
> pvc_protection_controller.go:111] Shutting down PVC protection
> controller I0907 10:44:01.949310       1 route_controller.go:125]
> Shutting down route controller I0907 10:44:01.949316       1
> service_controller.go:197] Shutting down service controller I0907
> 10:44:01.949327       1 deployment_controller.go:164] Shutting down
> deployment controller I0907 10:44:01.949435       1
> garbagecollector.go:148] Shutting down garbage collector controller
> I0907 10:44:01.949443       1 resource_quota_controller.go:295]
> Shutting down resource quota controller

Below are the docker logs from kube-controller since the restart (7th Sep):

> E0915 21:51:36.028108       1 leaderelection.go:306] error retrieving
> resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get
> https:--127.0.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager?timeout=10s:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915
> 21:51:40.133446       1 leaderelection.go:306] error retrieving
> resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get
> https:--127.0.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager?timeout=10s:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused

Below are the docker logs from kube-scheduler since the restart (7th Sep):

> E0915 21:52:44.703587       1 reflector.go:126]
> k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list *v1.Node:
> Get https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial
> tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915 21:52:44.704504
> 1 reflector.go:126] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed
> to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get
> https:--127.0.0.1/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915
> 21:52:44.705471       1 reflector.go:126]
> k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list *v1.Service:
> Get https:--127.0.0.1/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915
> 21:52:44.706477       1 reflector.go:126]
> k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list
> *v1.ReplicaSet: Get https:--127.0.0.1/apis/apps/v1/replicasets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915
> 21:52:44.707581       1 reflector.go:126]
> k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list
> *v1.StorageClass: Get https:--127.0.0.1/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915
> 21:52:44.708599       1 reflector.go:126]
> k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list
> *v1.PersistentVolume: Get https:--127.0.0.1/api/v1/persistentvolumes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915
> 21:52:44.709687       1 reflector.go:126]
> k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list
> *v1.StatefulSet: Get https:--127.0.0.1/apis/apps/v1/statefulsets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915
> 21:52:44.710744       1 reflector.go:126]
> k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list
> *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get https:--127.0.0.1/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915
> 21:52:44.711879       1 reflector.go:126]
> k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/server.go:223: Failed to list
> *v1.Pod: Get https:--127.0.0.1/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=status.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded&limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused E0915
> 21:52:44.712903       1 reflector.go:126]
> k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list
> *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: Get https:--127.0.0.1/apis/policy/v1beta1/poddisruptionbudgets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused

### kube-apiserver certificate Renewal:

I found the kube-apiserver certificate which is this one `/etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-client.crt` had expired in July 2020. There were few other expired certificates related to etcd-manager-main and events (it is same copy of the certificates on both places) but I don't see this referenced in the manifest files.

I searched and found steps to renew the certificates but most of them were using "kubeadm init phase" commands but I couldn't find kubeadm on master server and the certificates names and paths were different to my setup. So I generated a new certificate using openssl for kube-apiserver using existing ca cert and included DNS names with internal and external IP address (ec2 instance) and loopback ip address using openssl.cnf file. I replaced the new certificate with the same name `/etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-client.crt`.

After that I restarted the kube-apiserver docker (which was continuously exiting) and restarted kubelet. Now the certificate expiry message is not coming but the kube-apiserver is continuously restarting which I believe is the reason for the errors on kube-controller and kube-scheduler docker containers.

### NOTE:

I have not restarted the docker on the master server after replacing the certificate.

NOTE: All our production PODs are running on worker nodes so they are not affected but I can't manage them as I can't connect using kubectl.

Now, I am not sure what is the issue and why kube-apiserver is restarting continuously.

### Update to the original question:

Kubernetes version: v1.14.1
Docker version: 18.6.3

Below are the latest `docker logs from kube-apiserver container` (which is still crashing)

> F0916 08:09:56.753538       1 storage_decorator.go:57] Unable to create storage backend: config (&{etcd3 /registry {[https:--127.0.0.1:4001] /etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-client.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-client.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-ca.crt} false true 0xc00095f050 apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1  5m0s 1m0s}), err (tls: private key does not match public key)

Below is the output from `systemctl status kubelet`

> Sep 16 08:10:16 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx kubelet[388]: E0916 08:10:16.095615     388 kubelet.go:2244] node "ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.xx-xxxxx-x.compute.internal" not found

> **Sep 16 08:10:16 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx kubelet[388]: E0916 08:10:16.130377     388 kubelet.go:2170] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: Kubenet does not have netConfig. This is most likely due to lack of PodCIDR**

> Sep 16 08:10:16 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx kubelet[388]: E0916 08:10:16.147390     388 reflector.go:126] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list *v1beta1.CSIDriver: Get https:--127.0.0.1/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1/csidrivers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused

> Sep 16 08:10:16 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx kubelet[388]: E0916 08:10:16.195768     388 kubelet.go:2244] node "ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.xx-xxxxx-x..compute.internal" not found

> Sep 16 08:10:16 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx kubelet[388]: E0916 08:10:16.295890     388 kubelet.go:2244] node "ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.xx-xxxxx-x..compute.internal" not found

> Sep 16 08:10:16 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx kubelet[388]: E0916 08:10:16.347431     388 reflector.go:126] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list *v1beta1.RuntimeClass: Get https://127.0.0.1/apis/node.k8s.io/v1beta1/runtimeclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused

This cluster (along with 3 others) was setup using kops. The other clusters are running normally and looks like they have some expired certificates as well. The person who setup the clusters is not available for comment and I have limited experience on Kubernetes. Hence required assistance from the gurus.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Many thanks.

### Update after response from Zambozo and Nepomucen:

Thanks to both of you for your response. Based that I found that there were expired etcd certificates on the /mnt mount point.

I followed workaround from https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/advisories/etcd-manager-certificate-expiration/

and recreated etcd certificates and keys. I have verified each of the certificate with a copy of the old one (from my backup folder) and everything is matching and the new certificates has expiry date set to Sep 2021.

Now I am getting different error on etcd dockers (both etcd-manager-events and etcd-manager-main)

### Note:xxx-xx-xx-xxx is the IP address of the master server

> root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~# `docker logs <etcd-manager-main container> --tail 20`
> I0916 14:41:40.349570    8221 peers.go:281] connecting to peer "etcd-a" with TLS policy, servername="etcd-manager-server-etcd-a"
> W0916 14:41:40.351857    8221 peers.go:325] unable to grpc-ping discovered peer xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3996: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure
> I0916 14:41:40.351878    8221 peers.go:347] was not able to connect to peer etcd-a: map[xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3996:true]
> W0916 14:41:40.351887    8221 peers.go:215] unexpected error from peer intercommunications: unable to connect to peer etcd-a
> I0916 14:41:41.205763    8221 controller.go:173] starting controller iteration
> W0916 14:41:41.205801    8221 controller.go:149] unexpected error running etcd cluster reconciliation loop: cannot find self "etcd-a" in list of peers []
> I0916 14:41:45.352008    8221 peers.go:281] connecting to peer "etcd-a" with TLS policy, servername="etcd-manager-server-etcd-a"
> I0916 14:41:46.678314    8221 volumes.go:85] AWS API Request: ec2/DescribeVolumes
> I0916 14:41:46.739272    8221 volumes.go:85] AWS API Request: ec2/DescribeInstances
> I0916 14:41:46.786653    8221 hosts.go:84] hosts update: primary=map[], fallbacks=map[etcd-a.internal.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com:[xxx.xx.xx.xxx xxx.xx.xx.xxx]], final=map[xxx.xx.xx.xxx:[etcd-a.internal.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com etcd-a.internal.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com]]
> I0916 14:41:46.786724    8221 hosts.go:181] skipping update of unchanged /etc/hosts

> root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~# `docker logs <etcd-manager-events container> --tail 20`
> W0916 14:42:40.294576    8316 peers.go:215] unexpected error from peer intercommunications: unable to connect to peer etcd-events-a
> I0916 14:42:41.106654    8316 controller.go:173] starting controller iteration
> W0916 14:42:41.106692    8316 controller.go:149] unexpected error running etcd cluster reconciliation loop: cannot find self "etcd-events-a" in list of peers []
> I0916 14:42:45.294682    8316 peers.go:281] connecting to peer "etcd-events-a" with TLS policy, servername="etcd-manager-server-etcd-events-a"
> W0916 14:42:45.297094    8316 peers.go:325] unable to grpc-ping discovered peer xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3997: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure
> I0916 14:42:45.297117    8316 peers.go:347] was not able to connect to peer etcd-events-a: map[xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3997:true]
> I0916 14:42:46.791923    8316 volumes.go:85] AWS API Request: ec2/DescribeVolumes
> I0916 14:42:46.856548    8316 volumes.go:85] AWS API Request: ec2/DescribeInstances
> I0916 14:42:46.945119    8316 hosts.go:84] hosts update: primary=map[], fallbacks=map[etcd-events-a.internal.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com:[xxx.xx.xx.xxx xxx.xx.xx.xxx]], final=map[xxx.xx.xx.xxx:[etcd-events-a.internal.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com etcd-events-a.internal.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com]]
> I0916 14:42:50.297264    8316 peers.go:281] connecting to peer "etcd-events-a" with TLS policy, servername="etcd-manager-server-etcd-events-a"
> W0916 14:42:50.300328    8316 peers.go:325] unable to grpc-ping discovered peer xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3997: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure
> I0916 14:42:50.300348    8316 peers.go:347] was not able to connect to peer etcd-events-a: map[xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3997:true]
> W0916 14:42:50.300360    8316 peers.go:215] unexpected error from peer intercommunications: unable to connect to peer etcd-events-a

Could you please suggest on how to proceed from here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Generating a new cert using openssl for kube-apiserver and replacing the cert and key brought the kube-apiserver docker to stable state and provided access via kubectl.

To resolve etcd-manager certs issue, upgraded etcd-manager to `kopeio/etcd-manager:3.0.20200531` for both etcd-manager-main and etcd-manager-events as described at https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/8959#issuecomment-673515269

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to the ETCD. you may have renewed the certs for Kubernetes components but did you do the same for ETCD?
Your API server is trying to connect to the ETCD and giving:

```
tls: private key does not match public key)
```

As you have only 1 etcd(assuming on the number of master nodes) I would do a backup of it before trying to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Zambozo for your response. 

I checked `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/ etcd-events.manifest` and `etcd-main.manifest` files but didn't see any reference to certs. Where can I find the certs used by ETCD? 

To generate kube-apiserver cert, I used the `/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd-manager-events/etcd-clients-ca.crt` 

After this only I am getting the message `tls: private key does not match public key` and earlier with the expired certificate I was getting `err (context deadline exceeded)`.

Also how do I backup ETCD?

Please let me know if you need any further logs.

Comment: ETCD certs are in volume mounted by etcd-manager. To find them you need to ssh into master node and search in `/mnt` directory (`sudo find /mnt/ -name server.*`, `sudo find /mnt/ -name me.*`).
Do you know about existence of kops dedicated guide for [cert rotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/rotate-secrets.md) ?

Comment: Thanks @Nepomucen for your response. I can confirm that I found the ETCD certs on both the paths following your input and they had expired. Would it be ok to implement the workaround following this link https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/advisories/etcd-manager-certificate-expiration/ . I will look at the cert rotation once this issue is resolved. 

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I managed to renew all the ETCD certs under /mnt/*/server.* and /mnt/*/me.*. Now getting different error were it is not able to connect with peer. I have included logs from both etcd-manager-main and etcd-manager-events docker containers in the above question section. Requesting further guidance and really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: #Update: 

As mentioned in the question, I generated kube-apiserver cert `/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd-manager-events/etcd-clients-ca.crt`using openssl and replaced the expired cert but didn't replace the key file hence I was getting the error `tls: private key does not match public key`. Now I copied the key file using which I generated the cert and now kube-apiserver is running and I am able to connect using kubectl.

The issue with ETCD is still there and I will post that in my next comment.

Comment: # Issue with ETCD is still the same and I shared the errors / logs in the question (last section). From the error, I see etcd is trying to reach `connecting to peer "etcd-a" with TLS policy, servername="etcd-manager-server-etcd-a"`. I see a cert with this name under `/etc/kubernetes/pki/etc-manager-main` which is expired. So how can renew the certs under `/etc/kubernetes/pki/etc-manager-main` and `/etc/kubernetes/pki/etc-manager-events` folders? 

I renewed the ETCD certs used in /mnt/master*/pki by deleting pki folder from both the volumes and restarted etcd dockers which issued new certs.

Comment: you might be suffering from the known issue reported on kops's github project, so please read first the whole thread carefully, and try to upgrade the etc-manager version as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/8959#issuecomment-673535516).

Comment: Thanks @Nepomucen for your response.

Comment: Just please let us know whether it solved your issue or not.

Comment: @Nepomucen, sure will do. As of now I am yet to upgrade etcd-manager version. I have asked for a clarification on the github project thread as I don't have the directory structure mentioned by one of the user after etcd-manager upgrade.

Comment: @Nepomucen: Upgraded etcd-manager to `kopeio/etcd-manager:3.0.20200531` which resolved the issue. Thank you.